# How to split an equation at specific position and align it where there is a LaTeX operator

Tags: align, math-operators, split

I have a long equation in `twocolumn` article. The equation has a LaTeX operator like `\sqrt{}`. I want to split the equation at some position and align it inside the operator `...\sqrt{...&...}...\\&...`. This gives me error.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \exp(x)+\ln(x)+\sqrt{f(x)+&g(x)+h(x)}+\\
    &\ell(x)+x(x)+y(x)+z(x)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid long square roots. If you do, you can split the long argument into two lines. Typesetting in narrow columns often requires some compromise.

As another general rule, don't use `align` for single equations.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\exp(x)+\ln(x)+\bigl(f(x)+g(x)+h(x) \\
    +\ell(x)+x(x)+y(x)+z(x)\bigr)^{1/2}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you instead want that the + in the second line is aligned with one under the square root (which I can't see the need of), here's the trick.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newlength{\mylen}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\settowidth{\mylen}{$\displaystyle\sqrt{f(x)+{}}$}%
\begin{split}
\exp(x)+\ln(x)&+\sqrt{f(x)+g(x)+h(x)} \\
    &\hspace{\mylen}+\ell(x)+x(x)+y(x)+z(x)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP's `\sqrt` expression doesn't extend to the second row.

Comment: @Mico Then the question makes very little sense: I see no reason whatsoever for aligning the second line to something inside the square root.

Comment: @Mico Anyway, I added a simple solution.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you switch from `\sqrt{...}` notation to `[...]^{1/2}` notation.

Incidentally, if there's no natural alignment point across the two rows, you may want to employ a `multline` environment instead of an `align` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate column width

\begin{align}
  \exp(x)+\ln(x)+\bigl[f(x)+{}&g(x)+h(x)\bigr]^{1/2}+{} \notag\\
  &\ell(x)+x(x)+y(x)+z(x)
\end{align}
\begin{multline}
  \exp(x)+\ln(x)+\bigl[f(x)+g(x)+h(x)\bigr]^{1/2}+{}\\
  \ell(x)+x(x)+y(x)+z(x)
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```